# converting to the standard svn directory layout tags/branches/trunk

Tags: svn

We are working with SVN on a project. My collegues have already started the project by putting a simple directory "EX1" into the root of the repository, so there are no directories tags/branches/trunk.

I want to move the contents of this directory into the trunk, and then make a tag out of it.

Which commands do I have to execute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ cd <working copy root dir>
$ mkdir trunk branches tags
$ svn add trunk branches tags
$ svn move EX1 trunk/EX1
$ svn copy trunk tags/<tag name>
$ svn commit
```

Then my suggestion is to remove the working copy and check out a new one only for a branch/tag/trunk instead of the whole repository.